# Kafka cosmos db source connector fails saying schema mismatch even when there is no schema created before

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-cosmosdb, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

### Description

- When trying to create a new instance of source connector with value converter set to **io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter**. The lease container is created and a new schema is created and sometimes a few documents are written to the topic and then it fails.
- There is no schema defined before connector instance is created. but still we get the below error.

Kafka connect env settings:

```yaml
  CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: server-1:39094
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: "kc101-connect"
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: "_kc101-connect-configs"
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: "_kc101-connect-offsets"
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: "_kc101-connect-status"
      CONNECT_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter"
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: schema-registry:8081
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMAS_ENABLE: "false"
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter"
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMAS_ENABLE: "true"
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: schema-registry:8081
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "connect-1"
      CONNECT_LISTENERS: http://connect-1:8083
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_APPENDER_STDOUT_LAYOUT_CONVERSIONPATTERN: "[%d] %p %X{connector.context}%m (%c:%L)%n"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: INFO
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: 'org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest=WARN,org.reflections=ERROR'
```

Connect instance  settings:

```json
{
 "name": "cosmosdb-source-connector-tp-legs-raw",
 "config": {
   "connector.class": "com.azure.cosmos.kafka.connect.source.CosmosDBSourceConnector",
   "tasks.max": "1",
   "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
   "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
   "connect.cosmos.task.poll.interval": "100",
   "connect.cosmos.connection.endpoint": "{{CosmosDbUrl}}",
   "connect.cosmos.master.key": "{{CosmosDnApiKey}}",
   "connect.cosmos.databasename": "Preplanning",
   "connect.cosmos.containers.topicmap": "transport-plan-raw1#transport-plan-raw-events",
   "connect.cosmos.offset.useLatest": false,
   "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
   "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
   "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
   "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081"
 }
}
```

Error Message: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Failed to access Avro data from topic transport-plan-raw1 : Schema being registered is incompatible with an earlier schema for subject "transport-plan-raw1-value", details:

```json
[
  {
    "errorType": "NAME_MISMATCH",
    "description": "The name of the schema has changed (path '/name')",
    "additionalInfo": "expected: inferred_name_2092778255"
  },
  {
    "errorType": "NAME_MISMATCH",
    "description": "The name of the schema has changed (path '/fields/11/type/name')",
    "additionalInfo": "expected: inferred_name__1187958375"
  },
  {
    "errorType": "NAME_MISMATCH",
    "description": "The name of the schema has changed (path '/fields/11/type/fields/6/type/name')",
    "additionalInfo": "expected: inferred_name_762902212"
  },
  {
    "errorType": "NAME_MISMATCH",
    "description": "The name of the schema has changed (path '/fields/11/type/fields/6/type/name')",
    "additionalInfo": "expected: inferred_name_762902212"
  },
  {
    "errorType": "NAME_MISMATCH",
    "description": "The name of the schema has changed (path '/fields/11/type/fields/6/type/name')",
    "additionalInfo": "expected: inferred_name_762902212"
  },
  {
    "errorType": "NAME_MISMATCH",
    "description": "The name of the schema has changed (path '/fields/11/type/fields/9/type/name')",
    "additionalInfo": "expected: inferred_name_762902212"
  },
  {
    "errorType": "MISSING_UNION_BRANCH",
    "description": "The new schema is missing a type inside a union field at path '/fields/11/type/fields/10/type/1' in the old schema",
    "additionalInfo": "reader union lacking writer type: ARRAY"
  },
  { "oldSchemaVersion": 1 },
  {
    "oldSchema": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"inferred_name_2092778255\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"id\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"messageKey\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"shipmentNumber\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"shipmentIdentifier\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"shipmentVersionIdentifier\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"shipmentVersionCreatedDatetime\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"shipmentVersionUpdatedDatetime\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"shipmentStructureUpdateDatetime\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"containerServiceTypeLoadService\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"inferred_name_586916356\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"containerServiceTypeLoadService\",\"type\":\"string\"}],\"connect.name\":\"inferred_name_586916356\"}},{\"name\":\"containerServiceTypeDischargeService\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"inferred_name_1295212612\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"containerServiceTypeDischargeService\",\"type\":\"string\"}],\"connect.name\":\"inferred_name_1295212612\"}},{\"name\":\"cargoServiceType\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"inferred_name_1290169462\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"cargoServiceType\",\"type\":\"string\"}],\"connect.name\":\"inferred_name_1290169462\"}},{\"name\":\"shipmentRoute\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"inferred_name__1187958375\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"shipmentRouteIdentifier\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"shipmentRouteTypeCode\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"shipmentRouteTypeName\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"tradeLaneName\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"shipmentRouteCreatedDatetime\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"shipmentRouteUpdatedDatetime\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"shipmentRoutePointPlaceOfReceipt\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"inferred_name_762902212\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"routePointIdentifier\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"site\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"inferred_name_1587501840\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"siteIdentifier\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"definedAreaCode\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"definedAreaName\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"definedAreaTypeCode\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"definedAreaRelationshipTypeCodeParentArea\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"operationalFacility\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"inferred_name__1582750289\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"operationalFacilityIdentifier\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"facilityCode\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"facilityName\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"facilityType\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"inferred_name_1888608854\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"facilityTypeCode\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"isChildOf\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"inferred_name__1616517423\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"facilityTypeCode\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"isChildOfL1\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"inferred_name__2136641715\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"facilityTypeCode\",\"type\":\"string\"}],\"connect.name\":\"inferred_name__2136641715\"}}],\"connect.name\":\"inferred_name__1616517423\"}}],\"connect.name\":\"inferred_name_1888608854\"}}],\"connect.name\":\"inferred_name__1582750289\"}}],\"connect.name\":\"inferred_name_1587501840\"}},{\"name\":\"city\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"inferred_name__666696926\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"cityIdentifier\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"definedAreaCode\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"definedAreaName\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"definedAreaTypeCode\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"definedAreaRelationshipTypeCodeParentArea\",\"type\":\"string\"}],\"connect.name\":\"inferred_name__666696926\"}},{\"name\":\"territorialUnit\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"inferred_name__275936916\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"territorialUnitIdentifier\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"definedAreaCode\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"definedAreaName\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"definedAreaTypeCode\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"isoSubdivisionCategory\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"definedAreaRelationshipTypeCodeParentArea\",\"type\":\"string\"}],\"connect.name\":\"inferred_name__275936916\"}},{\"name\":\"country\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"inferred_name_206982570\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"countryIdentifier\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"definedAreaCode\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"definedAreaName\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"definedAreaTypeCode\",\"type\":\"string\"}],\"connect.name\":\"inferred_name_206982570\"}},{\"name\":\"locationFunctionCode\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"shipmentRoutePointCreatedDatetime\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"shipmentRoutePointUpdatedDatetime\",\"type\":\"string\"}],\"connect.name\":\"inferred_name_762902212\"}},{\"name\":\"shipmentRoutePointFirstVesselLoad\",\"type\":\"inferred_name_762902212\"},{\"name\":\"shipmentRoutePointFinalVesselDischarge\",\"type\":\"inferred_name_762902212\"},{\"name\":\"shipmentRoutePointPlaceOfDelivery\",\"type\":\"inferred_name_762902212\"},{\"name\":\"shipmentRouteLinks\",\"type\":[\"null\",{\"type\":\"array\",\"items\":{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"inferred_name__1469213405\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"shipmentRouteLinkIdentifier\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"shipmentRoutePointStartingPoint\",\"type\":\"inferred_name_762902212\"},{\"name\":\"shipmentRoutePointEndingPoint\",\"type\":\"inferred_name_762902212\"},{\"name\":\"shipmentRouteLinkSequenceNumber\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"routeLinkProductIdentifier\",\"type\":\"long\"},{\"name\":\"shipmentRoutingType\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"transportModeCode\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"transportModeName\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"waterAirLand\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"estimatedTimeOfDepartureLocal\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"estimatedTimeOfDeparture\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"estimatedTimeOfArrivalLocal\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"estimatedTimeOfArrival\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"voyageNumberStartsAt\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"voyageNumberEndsAt\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"vesselSchedule\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"inferred_name_1720401109\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"vesselCode\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"vesselName\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"alternativeCodes\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"inferred_name__1505900296\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"rksT_CARRIER_ID\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"rksT_CARRIER_NAME\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"rksT_SERVICE_CODE\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"rksT_SERVICE_NAME\",\"type\":\"string\"}],\"connect.name\":\"inferred_name__1505900296\"}}],\"connect.name\":\"inferred_name_1720401109\"}},{\"name\":\"shipmentRouteLinkCreatedDatetime\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"shipmentRouteLinkUpdatedDatetime\",\"type\":\"string\"}],\"connect.name\":\"inferred_name__1469213405\"},\"connect.name\":\"inferred_name_726885652\"}],\"default\":null}],\"connect.name\":\"inferred_name__1187958375\"}},{\"name\":\"_rid\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"_self\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"_etag\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"_attachments\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"_ts\",\"type\":\"long\"},{\"name\":\"_lsn\",\"type\":\"long\"}],\"connect.name\":\"inferred_name_2092778255\"}\"}, {compatibility: \"BACKWARD"
  }
]
```

Error code: 409

### Expected Behavior

- Connector instance should start pushing data into topioc

Comment: Are you able to get logs of the registry server? Or otherwise see what schemas are registered? Every unique event in the connector records creates a new schema. So, it's not possible to get an error if nothing is registered before... Also, you can remove `SCHEMAS_ENABLE` config since that doesn't do anything for Strings/Avro, only JSON

Comment: There were no schemas at all when I started the connector instance @OneCricketeer

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't mean more than one schema will not be registered when you do start it, and the very second event could be incompatible with the first. The error output seems to tell exactly what the issue is

Comment: Where does the documentation say anything except json is supported? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/kafka-connector-source#supported-data-types

Comment: It says here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/kafka-connector